# Replace text needs to be the output of a function whose input is capture in the regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to convert a log file to a format I can more readily process.

The input file consists of lines like the following:

```
Mon Nov 10 10:00:44 2014
AVYRLYST_001_DIREDBU7_P201_6179726.ps.zip

Mon Nov 10 11:25:58 2014
ADMMPPST_001_DEPTMPP_P201_6179809.ps.zip
```

I need the file to have the timestamp for each .zip file on the same line, but in yyyymmddHHMMSS format e.g.

```
20141110100044 AVYRLYST_001_DIREDBU7_P201_6179726.ps.zip
20141110112558 ADMMPPST_001_DEPTMPP_P201_6179809.ps.zip
```

I'm using a function from Shay Levy to help me go from `string` to `DateTime` and convert the date format accordingly and trying to use in a replace once I've done the rest of the reformatting.

However I'm struggling to get the captured output from the replace used as input to the function and the result of that used as the replacement text.

Below is the code I have:

```
function ConvertFrom-DateString 
{ 
    [OutputType('System.DateTime')] 
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Culture')] 

   param( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            Position=0, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
            HelpMessage='A string containing a date and time to convert.' 
        )] 
        [System.String]$Value, 

        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            Position=1, 
            HelpMessage='The required format of the date string value' 
        )] 
        [Alias('format')] 
        [System.String]$FormatString, 

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Culture')] 
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$Culture=$null, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='InvariantCulture')] 
        [switch]$InvariantCulture 
    ) 

   process 
    { 
       if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq ‘InvariantCulture‘) 
        { 
           $Culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture 
        } 

       Try 
        {            
                    [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($Value,$FormatString,$Culture) 
        } 
       Catch [System.FormatException] 
        { 
           Write-Error “‘$Value’ is not in the correct format.“ 
        } 
       Catch 
        { 
           Write-Error $_        
        } 
    } 

   <# 
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Converts a string representation of a date. 

    .DESCRIPTION 
        Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its 
        DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format 
        information. The format of the string representation must match the specified 
        format exactly. 

    .PARAMETER Value 
        A string containing a date and time to convert. 

    .PARAMETER FormatString 
        The required format of the date string value. If FormatString defines a 
        date with no time element, the resulting DateTime value has a time of 
        midnight (00:00:00). 
        If FormatString defines a time with no date element, the resulting DateTime 
        value has a date of DateTime.Now.Date. 

        If FormatString is a custom format pattern that does not include date or 
        time separators    (such as “yyyyMMdd HHmm”), use the invariant culture 
        (e.g [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture), for the provider 
        parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. 
        For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, specify 
        the wider form, “HH”, instead of the narrower form, “H”. 

        The format parameter is a string that contains either a single standard 
        format specifier, or one or more custom format specifiers that define the 
        required format of StringFormats. For details about valid formatting codes, 
        see ‘Standard Date and Time Format Strings’ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) 
        or ‘Custom Date and Time Format Strings’ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). 

    .PARAMETER Culture 
         An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information about the 
        date string value. The default value is null. A value of null corresponds 
        to the current culture. 

    .PARAMETER InvariantCulture            
        Gets the CultureInfo that is culture-independent (invariant). The invariant 
        culture is culture-insensitive. It is associated with the English language 
        but not with any country/region.             

    .EXAMPLE 
        ConvertFrom-DateString -Value ‘Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00′ -FormatString ‘ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz’ -InvariantCulture 

        Sunday, June 15, 2008 5:30:00 PM 

        This example converts the date string, ‘Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00′, 
        according to the specifier that defines the required format. 
        The InvariantCulture switch parameter formats the date string in a 
        culture-independent manner. 

    .EXAMPLE 
        ‘jeudi 10 avril 2008 06:30′ | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString ‘dddd dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm’ -Culture fr-FR 

        Thursday, April 10, 2008 6:30:00 AM 

        In this example a date string, in French format (culture). The date string 
        is piped to ConvertFrom-DateString. The input value is bound to the Value 
        parameter. The FormatString value defines the required format of the date 
        string value. The result is a DateTime object that is equivalent to the date 
        and time contained in the Value parameter, as specified by FormatString and 
        Culture parameters. 

    .EXAMPLE    
        ConvertFrom-DateString -Value ‘Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00′ -FormatString ‘ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz’ 

        Sunday, June 15, 2008 5:30:00 PM 

        Converts the date string specified in the Value parameter with the 
        custom specifier specified in the FormatString parameter. The result 
        DateTime object format corresponds to the current culture. 

    .INPUTS 
        System.String 
        You can pipe a string that contains a date and time to convert. 

    .OUTPUTS 
        System.DateTime 

    .NOTES 
        Author: Shay Levy 
        Blog   : http://PowerShay.com 

    .LINK 
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx 
   #> 

} 

#Read History Log, joining lines with spaces to get datestamps on same lines as filenames
$content = (gc K:\RUN-THUND-PSPRD_PRD-History.log) -join " "

#Replace ".zip" with ".zip" with a carriage return on the end
$merged = $content -replace '.zip',".zip`r`n"

#Trim Leading and Trailing Spaces
$Trimmed = $merged.Trim() -replace '  ',''

<# find all timestamps and replace them with converted timestamp in yyyymmddHHMMSS format 
e.g. to do this for one date string, the syntax would be:
'Sun Nov 09 13:19:09 2014' | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy' #>
$FixedTimeStamps = $Trimmed -replace '([A-Za-z]{3}\ [A-Za-z]{3}\ \d{2}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ \d{4})',
                                        ("`$1 | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
The term '$1 | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, fun
ction, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is co
rrect and try again.
At K:\CodeSnippets\PowerShell\ThunderHead_To_XML.ps1:154 char:43
+                                         (& <<<< "`$1 | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'")
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($1 | ConvertFro... HH:mm:ss yyyy':String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and when I alter my syntax on that last command slightly to ``` $FixedTimeStamps = $Trimmed -replace '([A-Za-z]{3}\ [A-Za-z]{3}\ \d{2}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ \d{4})',
                                        ("'``$1' | ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'") ```I get no error but the file entries end up like the following:

```
Tue Jan 06 15:39:08 2015 |ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy' ADMMPPST_001_DEPTMPP_P201_6218715.ps
.zip
```

So I think I'm not that far away, which is all the more frustrating!

Any help gratefully recieved.

**EDIT**

I'm still hopeful a way can be found to do this within the replace command, so I'll leave this open.

But, I've revisited my code meantime and have gone with the following code after the function definition, which works reliably, albeit it's a bit slow whilst it's in the `foreach` loop:

```
#Read History Log
$content = (gc K:\RUN-THUND-PSPRD_PRD-History.log)

#Change the datestamp format:

#first use select-string to get a table of dates using a regex
$dates = $content|select-string -pattern '[A-Za-z]{3}\ [A-Za-z]{3}\ \d{2}\ \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ \d{4}'

#next go through each match in turn, converting the date string to a DateTime object,
#then use -f to format as string in required format
$dates | foreach {
                $strolddate = $_.Line
                $dtolddate = $strolddate|ConvertFrom-DateString -FormatString 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'
                $strnewdate = '{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $dtolddate
                $content = $content -replace $strolddate,$strnewdate
                }

#join lines with spaces to get datestamps on same lines as filenames
$content = $content -join " "

#Replace ".zip" with ".zip" with a carriage return on the end
$merged = $content -replace '.zip',".zip`r`n"

#Trim Leading and Trailing Spaces
$Trimmed = $merged.Trim() -replace '  ',''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Powershell v2 I would do it like this:

```
$x = Get-Content .\logfile.log
$x = (($x -join "|") -split "\|\|")
$x | % {
  $i = ($_ -split '\|')
  $i[0] = Get-Date ($i[0] -replace '^\w+ (\w+ \d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+) (\d+)$', '$1 $3 $2') -f 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'
  $i[0] + ' ' + $i[1]
}
```

And for Powershell V3 I would use this:

```
$x = (Get-Content .\logfile.log -Raw) -split "`n`n"
$x | % {
  $i = ($_ -split "`n")
  $i[0] = Get-Date ($i[0] -replace '^\w+ (\w+ \d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+) (\d+)$', '$1 $3 $2') -f 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'
  $i[0] + ' ' + $i[1]
}
```

Comment: just about perfect - using the V2 code, I get an error for the very first date conversion. Think it's because the file being read in, the first line is blank, so the field that gets passed to `get-date` begins with a pipe

Comment: Fixed by adding the following to the end of the first line of v2 code - `| select -skip 1`